# "There is no server on port 443" Error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ssl, port

I used to access sharepoint site using sharepoint designer till yesterday.
Yesterday all of a sudden I am not able to access it using sharepoint designer.
I can access it in browser. When try to open the site in sharepoint designer, It says,

> There is no server on port 443 at 'mysite.com'.
>       You have selected the Connect Using SSL option. 
>       This connection problem may indicate that the server does not support Secure Socket Layer(SSL) communications, or that it uses SSL communications on a different port.

Now, is there a chance the site port has been changed? If yes, how can I change this port in Designer.

Comment: Although it is a ticket 4 years ago, could you add which SharePoint version you were using? If it was resolved please answer it below. It would be helpful to other visitors here.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bindings of the site in IIS if you have connectivity to the server to check the correct port number. If it has changed, add an alternate access mapping address from Central Admin.

Comment: since o365 is in the cloud is your solution applicable.I have the same issue.Clearing cache data did not resolve it.

Comment: @Rambokanambo no this is not applicable to O365. In fact, it is easier to resolve this in O365. Just raise a ticket to Microsoft and be patient while they resolve it themselves. :-)